# Are there any standardized steps in validating a circuit design?

Tags: circuit-design

I made a sensor front-end circuit for my thesis. The circuit works well as intended, but I think the design should be validated by standard methods.

Comment: well, have you exhausted all design rule checks and layout rule checks that your schematic capture software has? Have you looked for schematic and layout best practices (like drawing signal flow from left to right, decoupling sufficiently and locally, proper ground return paths)?

Comment: Design rule check, is that for the PCB? Yes, I have since it's built-in with my EDA.

Comment: Nomenclature depends a bit on the software package, but the design rule check typically applies to the schematic. By the way, "standard methods" might be a bit broad, it depends on what kind of board you're producing: standard methods for low-noise signal sensing boards will be somewhat different than for high-power motor control boards, will be different for high-speed digital boards.

Comment: `but I think the design should be validated by standard methods.` According to which standard(s) you need to validate? ISO? EN? Electrical? Safety? Accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question.

There are no "standard" ways to validate a circuit design. It depends on the purpose of the board and the functionality it should have - or in other words, what are the requirements of your circuit? (What kind of power source? how many inputs? how many outputs? types of each input\output, etc.)

Once you get a full list of requirements, you can think on how you will test your circuit to make sure that it functions as required. Example: circuit should work from a 200mAh battery for 3 days on average - you can test for average power consumption and calculate your battery life time (or any other method).

My answer refers to circuit design, but my experience shows that starting with requirements and test plan before starting the actual design is a method that can be used in various fields of development, with very good results.